# Create red bar when hover or click on nav

Tags: css, nav

I want a navigation section like the ones in youtube (www.youtube.com/friedpanseller) in the home, videos, about, discuss .When you highlight over them or click on them a red bar appears. How do i make that red bar appear.

Comment: Google is your best friend

Answer (score 1):

Use this example to illustrate your problem

If you want to keep the state of the active item then you need to include the navbar layout in every html file. For example if you click on Research then in the research.html your navbar must be

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
      <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
      <ul class="nav" id="nav">
        <li ><a href="#skdill" >skisll</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#skill">skill</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#research">research</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                 </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
And so on for all your links.

EDIT You can use JavaScript and do the trick:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
     <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </style>
  </head>

  <script>
     $(function() {
        $('#nav li a').click(function() {
           $('#nav li').removeClass();
           $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
        });
     });
  </script>

  <body>
     <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
              <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
                 <ul class="nav" id="nav">
                     <li id="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                     <li id="skill"><a href="#skill">Skill</a></li>
                     <li id="research"><a href="#research">Research</a></li>
                     <li id="link"><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```